# How to serialize Django models with nested objects (Django REST Framework)

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

If I have two serializers, where one is nested, how do I setup the restore_object method? For example, if I have the following serializers defined, how do I define the restore object field for my nested serializer? It is not obvious from the documentation how to handle such a case.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=30)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            instance.first_name = attrs.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            instance.last_name = attrs.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.email = attrs.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.password = attrs.get('password', instance.password)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    bio = serializers.CharField()
    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            instance.bio = attrs.get('bio', instance.bio)
            instance.user = ?????
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Important sidenote:** *It looks like you are using the old User/Profile methodology. Since Django 1.5 there is no seperation of the default User and your custom Profile models. You have to create your own user model and use that instead of the default one:* [Custom User Profile @ Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

### Serialization

I want to present you a different approach to serialize and restore models. All **model objects can be serialized** by using the following snippet:

```
from django.core import serializers
serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", myInstance)
```

or to **serialize more than one object**:

```
serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", User.objects.all())
```

Foreign keys and m2m relations are then stored in an array of ids.

If you want only a **subset of fields** to be serialized:

```
serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", myUserInstance, fields=('first_name ','last_name ','email ','password '))
```

To save the user profile you would just write:

```
serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", myUserProfileInstance)
```

The user id is saved in the serialized data and looks like this:

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "profile.UserProfile",
    "fields": {
        "bio": "self-taught couch potato",
        "user": 1
    }
}
```

If you want **related user fields in the serialization** too, you need to modify your User model:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, first_name, last_name):
        return self.get(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

class User(models.Model):
    objects = UserManager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('first_name', 'last_name'),)
```

When serializing with natural keys you need to add the `use_natural_keys` argument:

```
serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", myUserProfileInstance, use_natural_keys=True)
```

Which leads to the following output:

```
{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "profile.UserProfile",
    "fields": {
        "bio": "time-traveling smartass",
        "user": ["Dr.", "Who"]
    }
}
```

### Deserialization

**Deserializing and saving** is just as easy as:

```
for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", serialized_data):
    deserialized_object.save()
```

More information can be found in the Django docs: [Serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

Comment: That is an interesting approach, and I do agree with you that I should use the new model. But, how do I decide which fields to output. I am sure people using an API would not want to see "model": "profile.UserProfile"

Comment: Or should this be felicitated through the json module?

Comment: You can just use `serialized_json = simplejson.loads(serialized_data)` and provide only the fields part of the JSON: `serialized_json[0]['fields']`

Comment: btw, if you have questions feel free to ask and i'd be happy to dig a bit deeper into that topic. and if my answer helped please consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: This is a great find.  One correction however, the second argument to serializers.serialize() should be an iterator, so passing an instance will bork with a TypeError.  Wrap the instance in a list/tuple and you're good to go.  Tested in Django 1.6.2

Comment: Perhaps this has changed since this answer was first written, but trying to serialize single instances this way generates "Not iterable" errors. To fix, use e.g. `serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", [myUserProfileInstance, ])`