# Instance for nested serializer is not looked up

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework 3.1, I have a case as follows:

```
# models.py

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(ORGANIZATION_MODEL)

# serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

class OrganizationUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = OrganizationUser
```

I've simplified some of the above code to isolate the issue.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to update an OrganizationUser through a viewset, I'm getting a validation error:

```
{"user":{"username":["This field must be unique."]}}
```

In debugging, I found that the error is raised by UniqueValidator, and is because the user instance is not set on the username field's parent (i.e., UserSerializer).

So I added the followed to_internal_value implementation to OrganizationUserSerializer, and then it worked correctly:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):

    if self.instance:

        # set user instance on its serializer
        user = self.instance.user
        self.fields['user'].instance = user

        # make sure correct user is specified in request data
        try:
            user_id = self.initial_data['user']['id']
        except KeyError:
            raise fw_serializers.ValidationError('User must be specified')

        if user_id != user.id:
            raise fw_serializers.ValidationError('Invalid user specified')

    return super(OrganizationUserSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

But I thought that the REST Framework would have done this automatically? Is that not the case? Is the application responsible to look up any nested serializer instances?

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491008/how-to-serialize-django-models-with-nested-objects-django-rest-framework) specifically where it explains how to "related user fields in the serialization"?

Comment: Hi @Charlie: That question addresses Django serializers, not Django REST Framework serializers (the question title is misleading, because the self-answer offers the "different approach" of using Django instead of DRF).

Comment: I just edited the question to: (1) offer a solution while still posing question whether DRF should take care of it automagically, and (2) sharpen question to focus on the instance lookup rather than the validation error due to missing instance.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`queryset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument) kwarg?

Comment: Yes, I tried queryset kwarg, but it doesn't seem to be supported. I think queryset is used just for ListSerializer and related fields.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement this behavior by modifying UserSerializer's to_internal_value method:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    if data and data.get('username'):
        return self.Meta.model.objects.get(username=data['username'])
    return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

So now if you send some data to the UserSerializer that has a username as part of the data, it will assume you're sending in data belonging to an existing object, look it up, and return it.